# How to append a column to a DataFrame that collects values of another DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables (as Pandas' DataFrame), one is like

| name | val |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | 0 |
| name2 | 1 |

the other is

| name | tag |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | tg1 |
| name1 | tg2 |
| name1 | tg3 |
| name1 | tg3 |
| name2 | kg1 |
| name2 | kg1 |
| name3 | other |

and I want to append a column to the first DataFrame collecting all values of the second table by name, i.e.

| name | val | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 0 | [tg1, tg2, tg3, tg3] |
| name2 | 1 | [kg1, kg1] |

I know I can use row-wise operation to achieve this, but is there a way that I can use inbuilt Pandas' methods to do this? If I want to remove duplicates of the collected array in new_column at the same time, what method should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with aggregate `list`s:

```
df = df1.join(df2.groupby('name')['tag'].agg(list).rename('new_column'), on='name')
print (df)
    name  val            new_column
0  name1    0  [tg1, tg2, tg3, tg3]
1  name2    1            [kg1, kg1]
```